# Can you explain why this NavigationController setup works

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to understand how to setup a NavigationController. I don't understand why this code works with both a pushViewController AND presentModalViewController. I thought it had to be one or the other.

For context, this is a UIViewController that creates a UIImagePickerController. There are two view controllers after, the first (EditPictureViewController) edits the image itself and the second edits the properties. Believe I should use presentModalViewController.

...also is there a way to not dismiss the Modal View Controller so I can have a retake picture button on the EditPictureViewController?

Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init]; }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    EditPictureViewController *viewController = [[EditPictureViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self.navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:YES]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pushes the EditPictureViewController onto the NavigationController's view stack.

```
[self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Then you present the NavigationController here:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:YES];
```

I mean, all you're doing is presenting a modal view from a view controller and that modal happens to be a NavigationController.

Comment: ah. let me make sure I understand. The first line adds it to the navigation controller while the second line then shows the navigation controller. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The setup you have is not the "normal way it's done. The standard paradigm would be to create the navigation controller in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method, and set its root view controller to viewController, rather than pushing it. You normally think of "pushing" as moving to the next controller, whereas what you're doing is really just setting the root view controller in a non-standard way. Also you should be using the current methods for presenting and dismissing modal view controllers -- the ones you're using are depreciated. I'm not sure you need to set both of those transition styles either. Try commenting one out, and see if it still works.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    EditPictureViewController *viewController = [[EditPictureViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self.navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:self.navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}